# libc6-amd64 dependency problem

Tags: ati, package-management, dependencies, fglrx, 14.04

I'm trying to install fglrx manually from the AMD website however it keeps complaining that it's missing the dependency "libc6-amd64".

When I run the fglrx package through gdebi I get this message:

```
This package is uninstallable
Dependency is not satisfiable: libc6-amd64 (>= 2.9)
```

Even though it's installed...

```
dpkg -l | grep libc6
ii  libc6:amd64                                           2.19-0ubuntu6                                       amd64        Embedded GNU C Library: Shared libraries
ii  libc6:i386                                            2.19-0ubuntu6                                       i386         Embedded GNU C Library: Shared libraries
ii  libc6-amd64                                           2.19-0ubuntu6                                       i386         Embedded GNU C Library: 64bit Shared libraries for AMD64
ii  libc6-dbg:amd64                                       2.19-0ubuntu6                                       amd64        Embedded GNU C Library: detached debugging symbols
ii  libc6-dev:amd64                                       2.19-0ubuntu6                                       amd64        Embedded GNU C Library: Development Libraries and Header Files
ii  libc6-i386                                            2.19-0ubuntu6                                       amd64        Embedded GNU C Library: 32-bit shared libraries for AMD64
```

In the end, I managed to get fglrx to install using the below command which ignored all dependencies:

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-all fglrx*.deb
```

Though I was wondering if anyone knows how to fix this since in apt I now get this error:

```
apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 fglrx : Depends: libc6-amd64 (>= 2.9) but it is not installable
 fglrx-amdcccle : Depends: libc6-amd64 (>= 2.3) but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

Comment: Did you have a look at this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find a workaround while searching on google. I recompiled libc6 and its other packages. It fixed unmet dependency problem of Amd's binary Ubuntu package.

First, Add source code repositries on Ubuntu Software Center ( https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu )

I rebuilt libc6-amd64 Ubuntu package:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get --compile source libc6-amd64
```

I installed all eglibc (Embedded GNU C Library) packages with overriding problems.

Packages must created under directory that you gave "apt-get --compile source libc6-amd64" command:

```
sudo dpkg --force-all -i *.deb
```

Then, give same command to install your Amd Ubuntu packages:

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-all fglrx*.deb
```

It must install your Amd Ubuntu packages.

If you try to reinstall your Amd Ubuntu Packages, you have to reinstall libc6 and libc6-amd64 ( eglibc ) packages again.

It is my simple solution to fix dependency problem.

Comment: Thank you, it installs and works! But dependencies still stay in a broken state: `The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 fglrx : Depends: libc6-amd64 (>= 2.9) but it is not installable
 fglrx-amdcccle : Depends: libc6-amd64 (>= 2.3) but it is not installable`. Should I creat dummy package which provides libc6-amd64 2.9 to fix it?

Comment: Also had the same problem. The dependency problem is still there.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to fix problem:

a) Patching generated packages https://gist.github.com/dz0ny/b9e3fce83d0c52e16857

b) Generating virtual package libc6-amd64 which lists libc6:amd64 as dependecy